# Django translation system

Tags: python, django, translation

I have a small problem that I can't solve.
With reference to Django's automated translation system, I wanted to do a teaching test:

I went to django / contrib / auth / models.py in the AbstractUser class and in line 340 (Django version 3.2.7) I changed **_ ('first name')** to **_ ('dog')**

then I went to the django.po file located in django / contrib / auth / locale / it / django.po and there I inserted a new reference, that is:

msgid "dog"
msgid "cane"

i saved and restarted the server.

I logged into the administration panel and in the users section the name field comes with "Dog", but I was expecting "Cane" ...

What did I do wrong?

Thanks so much for the support!

Comment: For starters, you should not be editing Django core files. If you need to override a field in the User model, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model. — Secondly, did you [`compilemessages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/translation/#compiling-message-files)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the future I will definitely avoid modifying the Django code.  I didn’t do "compilemassages".  What is the command to execute (windows)?  Thanks for the support!

Comment: Read the documentation, it's also specifically for Windows: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin